# JQuery - Toggle CSS Attribute on Keyboard Press

Tags: jquery, css, keyboard, toggle

I'm trying to make a css attribute change when pressing the keyboard key "t".
Here is the code I have:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 116) {
        // if the user pressed 't':
        $("body").css("opacity", "0");
    }
});
```

The problem is when people click the key "t" it changes the css attribute to invisible; which is perfect. I need it to change again (to the previous state) when they click "t" again.
Apologizes for any mistakes I've made, I'm extremely new to jQuery. If you can help I would appreciate it.
Many thanks,
Toby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a class like this:

```
.active {
    opacity: 0
}
```

then toggle this class when your key was pressed using **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 116) {
        // if the user pressed 't':
        $("body").toggleClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 116) {
        // if the user pressed 't':
        if(!$("body").hasClass('active'))
            $("body").addClass('active').css("opacity", "0");
        else
            $("body").removeClass('active').css("opacity", "1");
    }
});
```